# Prevent click on link wrapper using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have link with image in it. This all construction is wraped in some divs. Problem : except image, also is clickable area of div-wrapper. I don't know why it is possible. So i want to prevent this behaviour. Now i can just do this with javascript (return false on div click) and with css (change curson type on div hover).

Can i somehow done this just with css?
Thanks.

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="home-left" class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div style="white-space: nowrap">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;width:200px;" border="0"/></a>
                <br/>
                <h4>Rating Categories</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m9bz7jh5/)**

---

For those who don't know what i'm asking : I want to make clickable area that are limited by sides of image. Now i can click on div that are wrapper of image to be redirected by link.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap and the img-responsive class makes an image a block element, you need to change that behavior. Block elements take up the full width of their parent container. You can fix that by making the image an inline element:

```
img.img-responsive {
    display:inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m9bz7jh5/1/)**

Or just don't use the img-responsive class.

Comment: I'd rather `display` the wrapper `a` as an `inline-block` element — [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m9bz7jh5/2/)

Comment: @HashemQolami - Sure, that'd work as well. The important part for the OP is that the class he's applying turns the image in to a block element.

Answer (score 1):

#### pointer-event:none;

Ya, you can do this using CSS :)
pointer-event:none;

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="home-left" class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap" class='no-link'>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;width:200px;" border="0"/>
      </a><br/>
      <h4>Rating Categories</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
  .no-link{
   
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your **jsFiddle** example, simply change yor code to:

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap; width:200px; margin: auto;">
```

The cause of the "side effect" is because your **A** TAG is taking all the parent **DIV** area, thus the **DIV** itself is taking the whole space of its own Parent, making it appears as if the *clickable* area is stretching beyond of the **A** TAG (which is not true).

To prevent such behavior it is always a good practice to limit the size of the container to the size of the *clickable* element inside it (**width** AND **height**, whenever necessary).

Have a good coding day! :)

Comment: i add width just to make image smaller, as somebody may not see problem from start

Answer (score 0):

You should use display: inline-block; and set the width of the containing div.

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="home-left" class="col-md-6 text-center" style="width: 100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <div style="white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;width:200px;" border="0" />
      </a>
      <br/>
      <h4>Rating Categories</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**just Add same margin and width in div also**
--example

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="home-left" class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div style="white-space: nowrap;margin: 0 auto; width: 200px;">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;width:200px;" border="0"/></a>
                <br/>
                <h4>Rating Categories</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```